# Firebase initialization. list of firebase app already initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to get the list of firebase app already initialized. I am using the below code to get the list of firebase app.

```
List<FirebaseApp> appList = Firebase.apps;
```

I am checking the list whether the app already exists.

I am using multiple firebase for my app, before initalizing Firebase.initializeApp i am checking in the above list whether it's already initialized or not.

First time the list return [FirebaseApp([DEFAULT])] and then it's throwing error saying before the "provision" app started initalizing.

> PlatformException(IllegalStateException, java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name Provisions already exists!, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name Provisions already exists!

Could you please help me to find what is the proper way to check firebase app initialized or not.

How to get list of firebase apps already initialized

Thanks,

Comment: not a suggestion but rather a clarification, what makes you use multiple firebase apps?

Comment: we have multiple flutter apps and we created multiple firebase app for those, and most of the data's are shared between apps.